# How can I parse an XML attachement file from a URL?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, dojo, httpurlconnection

I have a link which is `https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/dm/atom/library/ECD/document/AA/media/install.log.qkr` , on clicking this link, a window will promt to ask me if I want to open it or save it.

Either way, it's contents are XML,which are

```
<link id="2b46808042971cf480ad8db51e04c09f" formatVersion="1.0"><server url="http://quickr85.test.com:10040"/><library id="044e6100428e6550809e8db51e04c09f" path=""/><document id="2b46808042971cf480ad8db51e04c09f" path=""/><creator dn="" name="" email=""/></link>
```

The response's Content-Disposition is "attachment", Content-Type is XML.

I try to use DOM to directly parse this URL:

```
URL qkrFileUrl = new URL(requestURL);

// URLConnection urlConnection = new URLConnection();
URLConnection urlConnection = qkrFileUrl.openConnection();

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
String XMLFile = new String();
while(bufferedReader.readLine()!=null)
{
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    LOGGER.debug("Line is "+line);
    XMLFile += line;
}
```

but the result of XMLFile is a mess of JavaScript code:

```
Error 500: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <html lang="en-us" dir="ltr"> <meta http-equiv="X-LConn-Login" content="true"> <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">if (self != top) { try { // per Same Origin Policy, try to get top location attributes, if (self.location.hostname != top.location.hostname) { top.location=self.location; }catch(e){ document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display = 'none'; }} __iContainer_skip_init__ = true;<!--[if IE 6]><script>document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className+=" lotusui_ie lotusui_ie6";</script><![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]><script>document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className+=" lotusui_ie8";</script><![endif]--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="lotusBaseStylesheet" href="https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/_style?include=com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/base/package3.css&etag=20140502.131757" appName="webresources" base="https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/" query="?version=oneui3&rtl=false&etag=20140502.131757" theme="default" defaultTheme="default" oneui="3"></link><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="lotusThemeStylesheet" href="https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/_lconntheme/default.css?version=oneui3&rtl=false&etag=20140502.131757"></link><div class="lotusui30_layout"> <div class="lotusLoginContent"> <p>Find out more <a href="http://www-306.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/connections/" aria-label="More about Connections at IBM.com">at ibm.com</a></p> <p><a href="https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/help/topic/com.ibm.lotus.connections.common.help/euframe.html">Try the IBM Connections product documentation</a></p> <form class="lotusForm2 lotusLoginForm" role="main" method="post" action="/connections/resources/j_security_check"> <h1 class="lotusHeading">Welcome to IBM Connections</h1> <input id="service.name" type="hidden" name="service.name" value="ecm_files"> <input id="fragment" type="hidden" name="fragment" value=""> <label for="username">User name:</label> </p> <label for="password">Password:</label> </p> <span class="lotusRight" aria-hidden="true"><img role="presentation" src="https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/images/blank.gif?etag=20140502.131757" alt="IBM" class="lotusIBMLogo"><span class="lotusAltText">IBM</span></span> </form> </div> <script type="text/javascript"> serviceName: "webresources", contextRootEnabler: "/connections/resources",};var baseHost = "connectionsww.demos.ibm.com";var needProxy = (baseHost != window.location.host || baseProtocol+":" != window.location.protocol); isDebug: false, locale: "en-us", blankGif: "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/images/blank.gif?etag=20140502.131757", proxy: "/connections/resources/ajaxProxy",};<script type="text/javascript"> base: "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources", params: "etag=20140502.131757&lang=en&country=US"CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH || "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.oneui.ckeditor/editor/"; <!-- local script service: /web/_xdloader2?etag=20140502.131757&lang=en&country=US&_proxyURL=https%3A%2F%2Fconnectionsww.demos.ibm.com%2Fconnections%2Fresources&include=lconn.core.bundle_common.js%7E&html=true --><script type="text/javascript" src="https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/connections/resources/web/_js?include=lconn.core.bundle_common.js~&exclude=dojo.dojo.js~&etag=20140502.131757&lang=en&country=us"></script> dojo.addOnLoad(function() { if (fragment) { fragment = fragment.substring(1); input.value = input.value || fragment; try { if (dojo.indexOf([_u, _p], document.activeElement) === -1) } catch (e) {} var redirect = findRedirectInFragment("\/dm\/atom\/library\/ECD7B321-7729-430F-9F5C-9279D83EF13E;D826C8CD-2B72-4546-82AF-A3D23377C061\/document\/%7BF2CA2079-F96F-4B3C-8B87-5CB0B616D743%7D\/media\/install.log.qkr","",""); function findRedirectInFragment(redirect, base, query) { if (hash) { if (hash.length > 0) { hash = hash.substring(1); if (queryMarker != -1) { hash = hash.substring(0,queryMarker); if (hash.charAt(0) == "/" && base.charAt(base.length-1) == "/") base += hash; } return redirect; </script></html>null
```

Can someone enlighten me how can I parse the XML file? Thank you!

Comment: You actually don't get XML at that location! Check the URL... it contains a dmRedirect, so you can guess that either some JavaScript or a HTTP response header will send you off to yet another URL. Use curl to check if that's the case and use that one

Comment: @stwissel sorry it should just be dm...dmRedirect is a servlet I've written to parse the XML. I'm using some mod_rewrite to convert this original request URL.

Comment: Ok I see. The first step needs to be to establish that you actually call the right URL with the right credentials. Curl is your friend here. Also it is way easier to use the http client than an URLConnection. It seems what you get us either a redirect or a login, but not the actual file